# CS50 PSET6 server.c parse, load garbage memory, first "GET" call works, but second time 404 error

Tags: php, html, c, cs50

I have been trying to figure out why one of my variables attaches some garbage value the second time I make a call in gdb but cannot figure it out. I have diagnosed the problem but don't know how to fix it.

On the first call of "curl http://localhost:8080/cat.html", here is what the variables return:

```
temp = 0x7fffffff9c74 "/cat.html HTTP/1.1\r\n"

request_target = 0x607080 "/cat.html"

abs_path = 0x7fffffffbdd0 "/cat.html"

query = 0x7fffffff9dd0 ""
```

This works fine and the terminal does show the html file. However, the second time I make the call is where the problem arises.

On the second call of the same address, the following variables are returned:

```
temp = 0x7fffffff9c74 "/cat.html HTTP/1.1\r\n"

request_target = 0x607080 "/cat.html\327\254\367\377\177"

abs_path = 0x7fffffffbdd0 "/cat.html\327\254\367\377\177"

query = 0x7fffffff9dd0 ""
```

And then I will receive the 404 file not found error.

Does anybody know why and where I am accumulating all these random characters `("\327\254\367\377\177")`? I do believe that it is coming from the temp variable, but I have tried for hours to fix it but I still haven't been able to.

Below are my "parse" and "load" functions:

```
bool parse(const char* line, char* abs_path, char* query)
{
    // GET /cat.html?name="Alice" HTTP/1.1
    if (strncmp(line, "GET ", 4) != 0)
    {
        error(405);
        return false;
    }
    else if (line[4] != '/')
    {
        error(501);
        return false;
    }
    else if (strncmp(strrchr(line, ' '), " HTTP/1.1", 9) != 0)
    {
        error(505);
        return false;
    }
    char* temp = strchr(line, '/');
    int after_length = strlen(strrchr(line, ' '));
    char* request_target = malloc(strlen(temp) - after_length);
    strncpy(request_target, temp, strlen(temp) - after_length);
    if ((strchr(request_target, '"') != NULL || strchr(request_target, ' ') != NULL))
    {
        error(400);
        return false;
    }
    if (strchr(request_target, '?') == NULL)
    {
        strcpy(abs_path, request_target);
        strcpy(query, "");
    }
    else
    {
        int q_length = strlen(strchr(request_target, '?'));
        if (q_length != 2)
        {
            strncpy(abs_path, request_target, strlen(request_target) - q_length);
            strcpy(query, &strchr(request_target, '?')[1]);
        }
        else
        {
            strncpy(abs_path, request_target, strlen(request_target) - 2);
            strcpy(query, "");
        }
    }
    free(request_target);
    return true;
}

bool load(FILE* file, BYTE** content, size_t* length)
{
    if (file == NULL)
    {
        error(500);
        return false;
    }
    *content = NULL;
    *length = 0;
    BYTE buffer[BYTES];
    ssize_t bytes = fread(buffer, 1, sizeof(buffer), file);
    while (bytes != 0)
    {
        *content = realloc(*content, *length + bytes);
        memcpy(*content + *length, buffer, bytes);
        *length += bytes;
        bytes = fread(buffer, 1, sizeof(buffer), file);
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Do you mind writing your question starting from the beginning and not from some random position?

Comment: Sorry about that, the assignment is basically to implement a server. The parse function takes care of extracting the abs_path and the query from line, while the load function loads the file into memory. I could post the rest of the source code, but I'm afraid it might be too long as it is 1000 lines.

Comment: What main does is run an infinite loop that forever listens to commands. On my first command of "curl http://localhost:8080/cat.html", the correct html file is returned. However, on the second command of the same call, I receive what appears to be garbage values of "\327\254\367\377\177" and hence an error code of 404 (through another function) is returned.

Comment: Just for others' reference, it turns out that the problem was that I wasn't null terminating "request_target". I malloc'd an extra byte of memory, indexed to the last position and then set it to '\0' and it worked :')